# stubby does not compile on raspbian stretch

Tags: compiler-errors, raspbian

Hi I would like to use stubby on my raspberry setup which already runs a PiHole instance (hw is a pi3 with the current Raspbian Stretch Lite Release date:2018-11-13).

All the how_to's I found regarding that topic suggest the following approach:

```
sudo apt-get install libtool autoconf m4 libssl-dev libyaml-dev

git clone https://github.com/getdnsapi/getdns.git
cd getdns
git checkout develop
git submodule update --init
libtoolize -ci
autoreconf -fi
mkdir -v build && cd build
../configure --prefix=/usr/local --without-libidn --without-libidn2 --enable-stub-only --with-ssl --with-stubby
make
sudo make install
```

but regardless which way I follow, when I get to the make part, I get:

```
pi@PiHole:~/getdns/build $ make
cd src && make default
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/pi/getdns/build/src'
../libtool --quiet --tag=CC --mode=compile gcc -I../../src -I. -I../../src/util/auxiliary -I../../src/../stubby/src -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE   -Wpedantic -c ../../src/convert.c -o convert.lo
In file included from ../../src/convert.c:50:0:
../../src/util-internal.h: In function ‘_getdns_tls_version2openssl_version’:
../../src/util-internal.h:229:29: error: ‘TLS1_3_VERSION’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  case GETDNS_TLS1_3: return TLS1_3_VERSION;
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../../src/util-internal.h:229:29: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
Makefile:122: recipe for target 'convert.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [convert.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/getdns/build/src'
Makefile:53: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

What's the matter? When I inspect the referenced file I can confirm that the line with the "TLS1_3_VERSION" is the only ocurrence in the whole file, but what does the compiler want to tell me with this?

Can I do anything to fix it by myself, or is there a bug in the stubby source files from github?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I already got an answer from one of the maintainers on github.

Solution is to use the **master branch** instead of the develop branch (which was suggested by all the instructions I found in the HowTo's)

So, if anyone else is stuck with that error:

```
git checkout master
```

should fix it.